# How web developers storing the "huge string" in the backend database field

Tags: json, database, string, compression, large-data

I need to store a very large string into the backend table under one field which is of type string.

The string which I am storing is above 10 million (1 crore) character length. It is taking long time to store and retrieve from the backend.

I tried compressing algorithms,which failed to compress such large string. So what is the best way to handle this situation and improve the performance.
Compressing methods tried:

1.https://github.com/tcorral/JSONC

2.https://github.com/floydpink/lzwCompress.js

the above compressing methods weren't able to solve my problem.

Regards,

Saikiran

Comment: Wow, that's pretty big (lucky Michael Scott's not here). Is this something being read from and written into your db often? I assume there's no way you can break it up? Obviously you can cache it...but if it's that big the limiting factor is probably getting it to the client?

Comment: Hi Maverick, I am reading the data from an excel sheet (contains around 50k records)and converting it to the JSON , then stringify it and trying to store and retrieve it from the data base.It is working but taking a huge time.